# Copy from text file and paste onto csv using python

Tags: python, csv

I want to copy all the text from a .txt file and replace it with something in a csv file. To provide context, I want to copy an one-liner text from text.txt file (file only has one line: abcd) . I want to replace all the “../efgh” in the excel.csv file with the “abcd” from the test.txt file. I used the below code but there is no change occurring in the csv file. Please do let me know how to proceed.

```
#to replace 
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file :
filedata = file.read()
#filedata contains abcd
df = df.replace(['../efgh'], [filedata], regex=True)
df=df.to_csv (r'excel.csv' ,index=None)
```

Comment: the error is saying the `df` is NoneType... meaning it is nothing.  update your code with everything before those lines and maybe we can help

Comment: I assume because you haven't written any code to actually write to a file so it won't be updated

Comment: I have edited the code above to write to a file, failed to mention it in the code above itself. However, even with that there is no update. It remains the same but I am unsure as to how it can copy from the text file and replace the sub string in the strings in the csv.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df['column_to_replace'].str.replace('../efgh', filedata)

df.to_csv('excel.csv', index=False)
```

You need to specify on which column to perform the replace. Also you use the .str method to access the .replace method in pandas.

The replace method takes strings and not list, as you provided in your example.

Hope that it works!